# NoMethodError: undefined method `addrs' for #<Mail::UnstructuredField:0x007fc5c680bf18>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rspec

So I was testing emails with RSpec and the `email_spec` gem and I keep coming across this error that leaves me with no real clue as to what is causing it.

I am very new to RSpec and testing in general. When I googled this the error I found [one post](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/547) that was similar to this error as well as a [brief documentation page](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/UnstructuredField) on the error (which came off to me as very ambiguous).

I believe the reason is due to a possibly outdated gem or method from `email_spec`, but I am just *spec*ulating (there's a pun for your time).

This is the error I keep receiving (I redacted my email for this post):

```
1) UserMailer it sends an activation email when the user signs up should be delivered from XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
 Failure/Error: it { should deliver_from "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com" }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `addrs' for #<Mail::UnstructuredField:0x007fc5c680bf18>
 # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Few things to point out:

- I am not directly referencing the `addrs` method in any of my tests (so I believe)
- I have included `Email::Helpers` and `Email::Matchers` in my `config/test.rb` file.

Here is my UserMailer test:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "email_spec"

describe UserMailer do

  describe "it sends an activation email when the user signs up" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

    subject { UserMailer.activate_account(user) }
    it { should deliver_to user.email }


    # Error seems to be occurring from the "deliver_from" method
    it { should deliver_from "XXXXXXX2@gmail.com" }


    it { should have_subject "Please confirm to activate your account." }
    it { should have_body_text "Hi, #{user.first_name}" }
    it { should have_body_text "Confirm Your Account" }
  end
```

end

I would just like to be helped and pointed in the right direction as to what is causing this issue so I may take the appropriate steps to resolve it.

**EDIT**

Added the backtrace as requested.

```
# /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/field.rb:189:in `method_missing'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/email_spec-1.6.0/lib/email_spec/matchers.rb:92:in `block in matches?'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/email_spec-1.6.0/lib/email_spec/matchers.rb:6:in `address_array'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/email_spec-1.6.0/lib/email_spec/matchers.rb:92:in `matches?'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-expectations-2.99.2/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:24:in `handle_matcher'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:77:in `should'
 # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:116:in `block in run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:178:in `call'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:178:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:241:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:108:in `call'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:108:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:463:in `run_around_each_hooks'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:250:in `with_around_each_hooks'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:515:in `block in run_examples'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511:in `map'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511:in `run_examples'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:497:in `block in run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:497:in `map'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:497:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `map'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block in run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in `run'
 # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: Could you try running with full backtrace, e.g. `rspec -b /spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb`, and post the result here

Comment: Just added it for ya.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent! I was able to figure it out.

Issues was in my actual `UserMailer` class (in `/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`).

The `default from:` statement at the top did not match with my tests.

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "XXXXXXXX2@gmail.com"   #  <= This was the culprit

  def activate_account(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Please confirm to activate your account.")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this and my problem was that i hadn't provided a proper email address in the `:to` field

By mistake I had -

```
mail(to: @user)
```

Instead of

```
mail(to: @user.email)
```